# Node App Run Forever?

Tags: node.js, putty

I have 2 or more node app. That have to run forever if i reboot my PC that i don't want to start server it's automatic start for all node app.I used /ect/init.d node-app file and made some changes it's work but only for one node app but I have to many app on 1 server. Please any on help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do this:

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Comment: Yes, although I have only used it for running a single script. I believe it has the ability to run multiple scripts. Read the documentation listed on GitHub.

Comment: Yupe, Work it !!! fine On 1 server we run many app. But disadvantage is here we can't see console log like screen or node commands...But it's fine .. Thanks

But I updated here many things :  https://github.com/higunjan/foreverjs_Multiapp